# in rxjava get an error in android studio kotlin code

Tags: android, zip, rx-java

This code gives an error in Android Studio
what is the problem? Can you help me?
I want convert it to Kotlin code.when convert it in android studio get an error

please help me to convert to kotlin code.

```java
observable = Observable.zip(Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Tbl_Chat>() {
                    @Override
                    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Tbl_Chat> emitter) throws Exception {
                        if (chat_list!= null) {
                            for (Tbl_Chat chat : chat_list) {

                                emitter.onNext(chat);
                            }
                        }
                        emitter.onComplete();
                    }
                }),
                Observable.interval(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                (obs, timer) -> obs)
                .doOnNext(item -> {
                });
        observer = new DisposableObserver<Tbl_Chat>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Tbl_Chat chat) {


                chatList_adapter.addItem(chat);
                chat_list.add(chat);
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatList_adapter.getItemCount() - 1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: ");
            }
        };

        disposable = observable
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeWith(observer);
```

Comment: what is it saying ?

Comment: update code. i want to convert java code to kotlin

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

Missing code

```
    internal class Tbl_Chat()
```

Converted code

```
    val chat_list = listOf<Tbl_Chat>(Tbl_Chat(), Tbl_Chat(), Tbl_Chat())

    // fromIterable instead of Observable#create
    val iterator = Observable.fromIterable(chat_list)
    val interval = Observable.interval(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

    val obs = Observable.zip(iterator, interval, BiFunction { chat: Tbl_Chat, time: Long -> chat })
            .doOnNext { _ -> /* whatever */ }

    val disposable = obs
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            // subscribe instead of subscribeWith
            .subscribe({ _ ->
                // your side-effects for onNext
            }, { t: Throwable? -> /* logging */ }, { /* logging */ });
```

I have to say, that Observable#zip is probably not what you want. Most likely you want to use withLatestFrom/ combineLatest

Comment: where call   emitter.onNext(chat); in your code?

Comment: where call :  chatList_adapter.addItem(chat);
                chat_list.add(chat);
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatList_adapter.getItemCount() - 1);   in your code?? and where call emitter.onnext(chat);?